# $.post does not work when behind a proxy

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .post

i am working at a user tracking script , the code bellow works like a charm when simply visiting the [webpage](http://movingimages.comxa.com/) but when i use a proxy like [this](http://thefreeproxyserver.com/index.php?q=aHR0cDovL21vdmluZ2ltYWdlcy5jb214YS5jb20vaW5kZXgucGhwP3BhZ2VJRD0x) WITH the Remove Scripts unchecked the $.post part does not work /trigger and the user doesn't get inserted into the database . Can you please help me ? Thank you !   the file that contains the script bellow it's called ext.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var name =$("#user_ip").val();       
    var last_name = $("#user_location").val();
        ($.post('includes/track.php',{name:name, last_name:last_name , action: 'joined'}));
    setInterval(function() {
        $.post('includes/track.php',{action: 'list'},function(data){
            $("#onlinenow").html(data);

        });
    },10000);


$(window).unload(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/track.php',
        async:false,
        data: {name:name,action: 'left'}
    });

});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with your code.  It's a bug in the web-based proxy service you are using.  You can't expect services like that to work well... they have to fundamentally modify the content to work.  There is nothing you can reasonably do.

Comment: you were right there was a bug with that proxy, i have tried another and it works well . thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The web based proxy doesn't parse all the links in the code. So, you cannot blame your code. Also, it depends on the proxy too. How well it parses the URLs in the source.

Any proxy would normally parse the URLs in `href`, `action` and `src` attributes. So, in your case, to avoid such a situation, you can do something similar like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://my.domain.com/path/file.php">
```

And get the URL from the `<form>` tag using JavaScript, like this:

```
$("form").attr("src");
```

This would work because, the proxy will change the above code this way:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://my.proxy.com/proxy?url=http://my.domain.com/path/file.php">
```

And the JavaScript reads the right URL, rather than hard coding the URL as a string.

Comment: thank you for your response . The problem is :
 - there is no form submission ,when the page loads it executes some php script that adds the  ip and the current page url to   <input type="hidden" > then ajax does the rest .